# Java object structure most convenient for representing relational database

Tags: java, database, oop, relational

Suppose you can read a bunch of data in CSV files, containing some tables related to each other. What Java object structure, which uses standard Java collections available with JDK would be most adequate to represent relational database in anticipation of servicing the requests analogous to most common database queries, including standard selects, as well as count(*), select distinct(), group by, and other most common queries. The amount of data is relatively small, so that no memory issues will be anticipated, if we keep everything in memory.

Just want to emphasize, that this is not a question about SQL parsing, or about using in-memory SQL databases. This is just about most effective back-end relational database representation in Java, when you don't know all specific queries upfront.

Comment: I would think the most efficient way to represent relational data would be in a relational database.  Why not parse your CSV into SQLite and query that?

Comment: Well, that is more a theoretical question, just interested, how do they do it, say within SQLite internally?

Comment: how about a relational database?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to more clearly indicate that it's theoretical (in which case it might be better answered on [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)); as it it seems like you're asking for suggestion on how to implement a relational datastore, which is basically impossible to answer concisely.

Comment: dimo414 - thanks a lot for your interesting responses. You are right, I failed to formulate the question reasonably. It is not exactly theoretical question. Let's say you just have one CSV file, just one table, and it is not worth even going to SQLlite and H2 and it all can be fit within memory, so amount of data is not that big. What is the best way to represent this table as java object, anticipating queries you'll normally present to database table, but not knowing exactly upfront how you would need to query it?

Comment: I updated my answer (and you can comment directly on that if you have questions). I suspect however that you're not telling us what you really need to in order for us to help you.  Your question is essentially "I want to query some data, how should I do that?" which is impossible to answer beyond "With data structures".  If you share some specifics; what is the structure of the data, what sort of queries can you imagine wanting to run, how fast do you need it to be, how much memory can you use, and in particular why you're so averse to just using a database, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is *"What data structures do databases, like SQLite, use internally?"* the answer is far from simple, and is generally speaking implementation dependant.  A major selling point of different databases is how they choose to structure their data, after all.

In the case of SQLite, the [online documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) provides a lot of detail about its inner workings.  Other databases like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) similarly provide implementation notes in their documentation, but in general the data structures used are usage-specific and custom.

Speaking more theoretically, many database implement [indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) as [B+ Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) (among many other structures), but this is neither a requirement nor necessarily the "right" way to do it.  The data structures they use are a result of many years of trial-and-error, benchmarking, and hard work.

---

In response to your comment:

> Let's say you just have one CSV file, just one table, and it is not worth even going to SQLlite and H2 and it all can be fit within memory, so amount of data is not that big. What is the best way to represent this table as java object, anticipating queries you'll normally present to database table, but not knowing exactly upfront how you would need to query it?

I would use SQLite, or H2.  Both can be run [in-memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), and let you run arbitrary SQL queries against their data.  If you knew what you intended to query you could parse your CSV into a more special-purpose data structure, but if you don't know how you intend to query it, there is no way you can hope to create a more efficient data structure than existing database tools.  Databases are specifically designed for the use case of "I don't know what queries I'll be running against this data".